# adb got stuck. not starting in terminal command

Tags: macos, android

When I start the adb deamon using the terminal, it got stuck somewhere. Any idea why ?

[image]

PS: I am using OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Do you get some messages in Console.app  ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Nope nothing at all. It just always like that.. I have no idea why..

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your Android SDK? I had a number of small problems with Android and its tools when I upgraded from OS X 10.8 to 10.9 and reinstalling the SDK seems to have fixed them all.

Answer (score 2):

`killall adb`

and voilà, no more frozen adb terminal commands.
You can now proceed with `adb devices` to test and see if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
sudo adb start-server
```

Use your own password.

Opening port 5037 doesn't require privileged access, but there are some other flaky things with adb such as file/device permissions, etc. to which your own user account might not have access.

Comment: Still the same.. :(

Comment: Please, don't use sudo for this